# Yii2. Git не видит изменения в js файле

Tags: jquery, yii2, git, gitignore

Склонировал проект Yii2 себе на локальный компьютер. Развернул его, внес изменения в файл jquery.js, который находился в папке public_html/assets/f5d03095/ и сделал несколько других изменений в других файлах и папках проекта. После сделал git add и увидел что файла jquery.js не оказалось в списке измененных. Вопрос почему - в .gitignore такого ограничения нет, но при попытке добавить именно этот файл выдает что запрещено gitignore-ом. Я правильно понял что в папке assets хранятся копии скриптов и стилей? то есть мне надо было менять этот файл в другом месте? в папке vendors?

Comment: опечалю, и `assets` и `vendor` - "неприкосновенные" папки с вашими активами, собственные файлы же можно хранить практически где душе угодно, читайте [документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html). Очень интересно, что же может понадобиться поменять в файле `jquery.js`?

Answer (score 0):

не воспроизводится:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:yiisoft/yii2.git \
&& mkdir -p public_html/assets/f5d03095/ \
&& touch public_html/assets/f5d03095/jquery.js \
&& git add public_html/assets/f5d03095/jquery.js
```

выполняется без каких-либо ошибок.

вероятно, у вас имеется файл(ы) `.gitignore` в каком-либо из каталогов в пути к файлу `public_html/assets/f5d03095/jquery.js`